# Validation checking using nested if

Tags: java

Is using nested if for validation checking not a good practice ? The question is to have a length limitation checking on a value, throw a custom exception if not, and the entity value is set if it is not empty. I have been advised that doing checking like the following should be avoided due to the use of nested if.

```
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
 if (value.length() > MAX_LEN) {
   //throwing business exception
   throwBusinessException(value);
  }

  entity.setValue(value);
}
```

I have thought of various ways to do, but all seems to make things complicated, such as using Optional. (the custom exception checking cannot be used inside "ifPresent" as it cannot throw exception there)

```
Optional<String> value = Optional.ofNullable(request.getValue());
if (value.isPresent() && value.get().length() > MAX_LEN) {
  //throwing business exception
  throwBusinessException(value);
}

value.ifPresent(v -> {
  if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(v)) {
    entity.setValue(v);
  }
});
```

It is suggested to use like following. I wonder if this will be better than the first version. And this lead to the question of how to think about if a piece of code can be made better or not.

```
value = ObjectUtils.isEmpty(value) ? StringUtils.EMPTY : value;

if (value.length() > MAX_LEN) {
  //throwing business exception
  throwBusinessException(value);
}

if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {  
  entity.setValue(value);
}
```

Comment: the requirement is that the business exception is thrown only when the length is greater than MAX_LEN. When the value is null, empty or empty space, no action should be taken. it seems difficult to use a single if statement while satisfying this requirement

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The boolean expressions in nested `if` statements can usually be combined using the logical *AND* operator, i.e. `&&`.

This does seem appropriate for the first code block in your question. In other words, you can rewrite the nested `if` statements as follows.

```java
if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value) && value.length() > MAX_LEN) {
    //throwing business exception
    throwBusinessException(value);
}
else if (StringUtils.isNotBlank(value)) {
    entity.setValue(value);
}
```

According to the [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html) for class `org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils`, method `isNotBlank` is null safe.

Comment: The difficulty is that, the requirement also requires that the entity value should only be set if it is not null, empty or empty space. So it seems need one more checking before setting the entity value, but it will then have a duplicate checking of empty value. I wonder if there is way to have no duplicate of validation checking, but at the same time avoid using the nested if.

Comment: @sea then I would say that your original, nested `if` is appropriate. Did the person who advised you to avoid nested `if`s provide a justification or reasoning behind the advice?

Comment: it is being said in using nested if, if in future there is new if statement, it may further complicate the whole structure. The justification seem to be from the perspective of extensibility. I am not sure if nested if should actually generally be avoided as per best practice, as I sometimes use it and I have seen it's being used often in projects.